# Updating old 'English.lproj" convention to modern 'en.lproj' one?

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization, country-codes

I'm working on a new project with an old dependency. The dependency has localization which is sorted in directories with the longer format names (English.lproj, German.lproj, etc.), but the new project is using the newer country codes (en.lproj, de.lproj).

Is there a hassle-free way to handle this? The old dependency is also used in a few other projects so I'd like to avoid ripping it apart too much if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping there is a better way than this (perhaps you can try the XCode project validation feature such as [shown here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-4-project-modernization.html), you never know), but manual edits are documented here: http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=224

It's a three-years old document though, so it might be out of date.